# Determine the conditions on $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$, if any, in order to guarantee that the linear system is consistent.

Tags: matrices

Determine the conditions on $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$, if any, in order to guarantee that the linear system is consistent.

$x + 3y − 2z = b_1$

$5x − 5y + 4z = b_2$

$−3x + 11y − 8z = b_3$.

Consider the system of equations

$x + y + 2z = a $

$x + z = b$

$2x + y + 3z = c$.

Show that in order for this system to be consistent, $a$, $b$, and $c$ must satisfy $c=a+b$.

I need to determine the conditions of the $b$'s. I tried to solve this by using Gauss elimination to convert it into echelon form, but that seems unnecessarily cumbersome to solve this. I was hoping there would be an easier way to do this as well as for the the second part it seems they need the same concept which I don't know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The second one, just add the first two equations.

Comment: Gauss elimination is the best way to solve this. It only requires two steps. Once the left hand side is in echelon form, the conditions on the constant terms will be given by the equations in which the left hand side is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the condition you are looking for is known (more often than not) as the [Rouché-Capelli theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem).

You construct the matrix of the coefficients of the equations $A$; in the first case:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &3& -2\\
5 &-5&4\\
-3&11&-8
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then, you impose that the rank of $A$ is equal to the rank of the augmented matrix you get by adding the right-hand sife of each equation to each row of $A$; in the first case:
$$ [A|b] = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &3& -2&b_1\\
5 &-5&4&b_2\\
-3&11&-8&b_3
\end{bmatrix}.$$

If $A$ and $[A|b]$ have the same rank, the system has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3214716/265466), a different way of characterizing the equal-rank condition is that $(b_1,b_2,b_3)^T$ must lie in the column space of the coefficient matrix $A$ for there to be any solution at all, so what you’re really looking for is a description of this space. Row-reducing $A^T$ (equivalently, *column*-reducing $A$) will generate a “nice” basis, in the sense that the basis vectors have a simple, regular structure. In this case, $$\begin{bmatrix}1&5&-3\\3&-5&11\\-2&4&-8\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}1&0&2\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$ so a basis for $C(A)$ consists of $(1,0,2)^T$ and $(0,1,-1)^T$. In other words, every vector in $C(A)$ is of the form $b_1(1,0,2)^T+b_2(0,1,-1)^T = (b_1,b_2,2b_1-b_2)^T$, which gives you the condition $b_3=2b_1-b_2$. Similarly, in the second problem you can compute the basis $\{(1,0,1)^T,(0,1,1)^T\}$, from which $c=a+b$.